# Accessing an internal page from an internal system using the external network?

Tags: http, system-monitoring

I am kinda new to this. I am setting up a Zabbix web-check for an internal service. But the URL needs to be hit from outside the internal network to get the right output. I do not want to have to set up VPN stuff, ideally. What are my options in going about this? Are there services like httpstatus.io that offer APIs? Any other ideas I have not thought of? I want to know all my options before selecting what to do. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation here. 
In my case, I simply use our proxy to make these checks, you can define it in your web scenario.